# scroll a page when edit text gets focus

Tags: android, scroll

I am using the following code to scroll a page to the bottom when an `edittext` gets focus:

```
fcListener = new OnFocusChangeListener() {
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (hasFocus)                   
                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Page.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_DOWN);                         
                    }
                },300);
        }
    };

personNameText.setOnFocusChangeListener(fcListener);
```

However, whenever i click on the editText, it gains focus for barely an instant after which the page scrolls down. Then the edittext looses focus. This happens every time. How can I prevent the loss of focus but still make the page scroll down?

Comment: I don't quite get why you want to scroll down, and it might be confusing for users since it's not the expected behavior, but the ScrollView is known to mess with the focus. Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7114179/642161) for a way to deal with the default behavior.

Comment: there is a button below the editText field which i want to be visible when the editText has focus

Comment: I see, well that code will make the scrollview keep the focus. It's not ideal, but I've yet to find another way.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to scroll using custom code, use android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" on the activity, in Android Manifest.xml.

Comment: I used it but no resizing happened, the keyboard just overlapped the bottom of the page